# how to append content of a string variable to a file using os.system

Tags: python, subprocess

I have string

```
buff = "abc\ndef\n"
```

I need to write the contents of this string to a file using os.system

```
os.system('echo -e ' +buff+' > 123.txt')
```

This is th error i am getting

```
>>> os.system('echo -e ' +buff+' > 123.txt')
abc
sh: line 1: def: command not found
```

0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encapsulate your string with quotes, because it contains newlines:

```
os.system('echo -e "' + buff + '" > 123.txt')
```

or

```
os.system("echo -e '" + buff + "' > 123.txt")
```

This only works if your text does not contain double quotes or quotes.